# 3D Matrix multiplication with vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

This bothers me a bit:

Suppose you have a matrix with three layers.

Is there a simple way to multiply this matrix with a vector of three elements so that the first layer (all elements) gets multiplied with the first element of the vector and so on...

Now I have to use a function to do it like this:

```
function out=fun(matrix,vector)

out=matrix;
for k=1:3
    out(:,:,k)=out(:,:,k)*vector(k);
end
```

Is there a efficient way to do this in just one line without the need for a function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One very terse solution is to [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) `vector` into a 1-by-1-by-3 matrix and use the function [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) to perform the element-wise multiplication (it will replicate dimensions as needed to match the sizes of the two input arguments):

```
newMatrix = bsxfun(@times,matrix,reshape(vector,[1 1 3]));
```

Comment: wish I could upvote you once more for "rep beggar" :) Surprisingly, Jonas and someone else had a similar comment today and I've had to remind people of etiquette few times in the past. It certainly does seem like there's been an influx of one-time question askers who abandon field once the issue is resolved. But then, I haven't been here long enough, so this might actually be normal.

Comment: @yoda: Yeah, it's pretty common to see drive-by users who post once and never return. Can't do much about that. However, when I see a new user who asks a few sensible well-written questions, gives good feedback on comments, and generally behaves in a positive manner, I think it's worth *gently* pointing them to some FAQs detailing more of the inner workings of SO. I figure they may be more likely to return if they learn more about it, and we need more users like that.

Comment: Agreed, and I like the way you pointed him in the right direction. I'm going to steal that for future use :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a matlab function called `repmat` that'll help you in this.

```
M = [1 2 3]
M * repmat([1 2 3], 3,1)
ans =

 6    12    18
 6    12    18
 6    12    18

M = [1 2 3]
M .* repmat([1 2 3], 3,1)
ans =

 1     4     9
 1     4     9
 1     4     9
```

Depending on how exactly you want to organise your matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to repeat vector to match the matrix by size:

```
out = out.*shiftdim(repmat(vector(:),[1 size(out(:,:,1))]),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to gnovice's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681196/3d-matrix-multiplication-with-vector/5681307#5681307), you can also replicate your vector along the other dimensions and do a direct element wise multiplication.

```
A=randn(1000,1000,3);%# this is your matrix
vector=[1,2,3];%# this is your vector

[dim1 dim2 ~]=size(A);
replicatedVector=repmat(reshape(vector,1,1,3),[dim1,dim2,1]);
out=A.*replicatedVector;
```