# How do I multiply 3 vectors and obtain a 3D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

What I'm trying to do is obtain results like the snippet below without a loop.

```
x = [1 2 3 4];
y = [2 3 4];
z=[7 8];

[x'*y]

for k=1:size(z, 2)
z2(:,:,k)=[x'*y]*z(k);
end

z2
```

Loops may slow down MATLAB, however. How do I approach the task without them?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311944 check out the FEX links in the answers

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this because `z` is ` vector:

```
bsxfun(@times, reshape(z, 1, 1, []), [x'*y])
```

If `z` was a 2D matrix itself and you wanted to do a matrix multiplication at each level then you would need to use the links I posted in my comment. But because each time you are multiplying by a scalar, you can use `@times`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681196/3d-matrix-multiplication-with-vector). Base on this, you could do as follows:

```
x = [1 2 3 4];
y = [2 3 4];
z=[7 8];


% replicate [x'*y] into 3D array.
d = repmat([x'*y], [1, 1, numel(z)])

% multiplay by z vector
z2 = bsxfun(@times, d, reshape(z,[1, 1, numel(z)]))
```