# what is the matlab way without loop to multiply a matrix with a vector (extending to the 3rd dim)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

A simple example to illustrate all elements of a matrix multiplying each element of a vector to generate a 3D array.

```
M = reshape(1:12,4,3);
V = 1:2;
n = length(V);
A = nan([size(M),n]);
for ii = 1 : n
  A(:,:,ii) = M * V(ii);
end
```

then

> A(:,:,1) =
>
> ```
>  1     5     9
>  2     6    10
>  3     7    11
>  4     8    12
> ```
>
> A(:,:,2) =
>
> ```
>  2    10    18
>  4    12    20
>  6    14    22
>  8    16    24
> ```

Or by `repmat` both `M` and `V` to the size of `[4,3,2]`,

```
A = repmat(M,1,1,n) * reshape(V(ones(size(M)),:),[size(M),n])
```

It creates two 3D array by `repmat` besides the resulting 3d array `A`.

How to make it efficiently WITHOUT `for` loop and save the memory use?

According to the answer by @Lincoln,

```
A = bsxfun(@times, repmat(M,1,1,n), reshape(1:n, 1, 1, n));
```

`repmat` the vector `V` to 3d is not necessary.

Is it possible to create **NO** 3d array if the final result wanted is 2d, the sum of `A` along the 3rd dim? By `for` loop, the code would be

```
M = reshape(1:12,4,3);
V = 1:2;
n = length(V);
A = 0;
for ii = 1 : n
  A = A + M * V(ii);
end
```

Comment: Use bsxfun http://stackoverflow.com/a/5681307/2732801

Comment: @percusse  in the first code snippet, `n = length(V)`

Comment: what happened to my comment I don't know. But for n=2 you don't have much benefit from vectorization.

Comment: @percusses the code snippet is a simple demonstration to clarify my problem. The true data are quite large. I cannot print millions of lines here.....

Comment: That's why I asked what `n` is in your application but nevermind.

Comment: @percusse  in the real application, `n`>=1e6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `for.. loop` with:

```
M_rep = repmat(M,1,1,n) %//repeat M in the 3rd dimension n times
v = reshape(1:n, 1, 1, n) %//create a vector [1 2 .. n] pointing in the third dimension
A = bsxfun(@times, M_rep, v) %//vector multiply them in the third dimension
```

In your above example, `n=2`.

EDIT (to your added question): To sum without allocating A:

```
B = sum(bsxfun(@times, M_rep, v),3);
```

Comment: is it able to avoid the allocation of 3d array if the result is 2d (sum A over dim 3)?

Comment: i don't really understand your question.. allocation of which 3d array? and what result being 2d?

Comment: I added a code demonstration to the end of the post. please take a look.

Comment: currently, `M_rep` and `A` are 3D.